# How Do The Integration of The Given Expression Is $27\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Basically, this is a double integration question from the book *Calculus 2* by Howard Anton. Half of the question is resolved and now I'm at this stage where I can't prove the left hand side to the right hand side.

$$
\int_{-3}^3 (6\sqrt {9-x^2} - 2x \sqrt{9-x^2}) dx = 27\pi
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is, you don't need to use substitutions or take integration of basic trigonometric functions.

All you need is to see $x*\sqrt{9-x^2}$ is odd function and have no contribution under integration over {-3, 3}. And for the rest, $6*\sqrt{9-x^2}$, you should see that it is 6 times the area of upper half of the circular region defined with center origin and radius 3, that is $ 6* \frac{9*{\pi} }{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we don't see it like this and simply integrate it and then put the limits, then the whole expression equals to zero. How is it possible that if we solve it with one mathematical technique the answer is 27pi and with the other mathematical technique it is zero?

Comment: @OmarTariq But how *do* you "simply integrate"? By substitution? Whatever you're doing, I'm pretty sure I know why you get zero. Firstly, you kept the limits of integration as they are, and did not use properties of the integrand. Secondly, (this is subtle), you missed the fact that $\sqrt{9 - x^2}$ is, by definition, the *positive* square root. So for example, if you use a substitution $x = 2 \sin t$, then $\sqrt{9 - x^2} = 3 |\cos t|$, and *not* $3 \cos t$. If you don't notice this, the integral vanishes (since the integrand would then be an odd function, and the interval is symmetric).

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $x=3\sin u$ and use $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$. Note that the integral over the second term vanishes by symmetry.

Alternatively, note that the integral over the first term is the area of a semicircle.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $\sqrt{9 - x^2}$ is an even function and $x \sqrt{9 - x^2}$ is an odd function. Therefore, the given integral is equal to
\begin{equation*}
2 \times \int_0^3 6 \sqrt{9 - x^2} \,\mathrm dx = 12 \int_0^3 \sqrt{9 - x^2} \,\mathrm dx.
\end{equation*}

Now, substituting $x = 3 \sin t$, the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
12 \int_0^{\pi/2} (3 \cos t) (3 \cos t)\,\mathrm dt & = 12 \times 9 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2 t\,\mathrm dt\\
& = 12 \times 9 \times \dfrac 1 2 \times \dfrac {\pi} 2\\
& = 27\pi.
\end{align*}